# Is it possible to provide a null implementation when registering something on Flutter's GetIt?

Tags: flutter, dependency-inversion, get-it

Given we use third-party packages, one of them expects to receive a null in the production code and a custom implementation in the test code. So, it'll be convenient to have a GetIt provider that gives us `null` on production while an actual tailored implementation on tests.

We tried `getIt.registerSingleton<OurOwnInterface?>(()=>null);` but it doesn't even compile. And the documentation doesn't specify if that's possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is wrap it with a `try catch`:

```dart
OurOwnInterface? _getOurOwnInterface() {
  try {
    return GetIt.I.get<OurOwnInterface>();
  } on StateError catch (_) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

The complete gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/luisfelipeas5/e39b6fee76eb2d2bd7a35b8ba67828d6)

Edit:

```dart
extension GetItExtension on GetIt {
  T? getOrNull<T extends Object>() {
    try {
      return GetIt.I.get<T>();
    } on StateError catch (_) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

//and then use like:
OurOwnInterface? appModel = GetIt.I.getOrNull();
```

Comment: Yes, did that... but it's not wonderful...

Comment: Fair, @RocBoronat. But, if this logic is wrapped in an extension of GetIt method, could be easy to re-use and alter later. What you think? (I could edit my answer with this suggestion if you aggree

Comment: Hey! That's great actually! I guess there's no other way to do it, right? I mean, GetIt doesn't have it. We have to extend it.

Comment: good! Yeah, I don't think we can achieve with the "standard" methods.

Comment: Perfect. Done it and working on production already :·) Thanks a lot for it, Luis Felipe!